# manage.py dbshell not working with PyCharm 2.7.1

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Whenever I try to run `manage.py dbshell` on PyCharm 2.7.1, it keeps on running, but never gives anything.

Could anyone please explain why this is happening? I am using `sqlite3`, and I added `sqlite3` to the `PATH` variable, so there should not be a problem.

Comment: Nope. Gave PyCharm admin privileges too. On windows. Even set db place to `C:\\`. It still does not work.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6882 may be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've found this to be a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6882).